# php - Adding another variable for validation in login

Tags: php

Im trying to login with another variable for a different role which is inside my database. I have a column which is `user_role` that is set to `varchar`(Yes, it isn't a good practice sorry) that can only have a `Student` and `Administrator` (It is a string, in case you miss that it is a varchar). In my posted code below. I want to validate if it is a Student or an Admin. If it is a `Administrator` it will go to `dashboard.php` but when it is a student it will go to `dashboard_student.php`

```
$sel_admin = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username='$username'";
                                $rs_admin = mysql_query($sel_admin);
                                $rs_count = mysql_num_rows($rs_admin);

                                if($rs_count<1){
                                    echo 'Invalid username!';
                                }else{
                                    $admin_info = mysql_fetch_array($rs_admin);
                                    $adminid = $admin_info['user_id'];
                                    $db_password = $admin_info['user_password'];
                                    if($password == $db_password){
                                        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $adminid;

                                        header("location: dashboard.php");
                                    }else{
                                        echo 'Incorrect password!';
                                    }
```

I belive it is somewhere in `if($password == $db_password)` that i should work, but i don't have any idea how to put it.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. Make sure you've also started the session and add `exit;` after header.

Comment: using mysql deprecated use PDO instead , and what does you inserted in the user_role while register process

Comment: Im sorry tom but i don't understand what you are trying to say. But from what you are saying i guess.. The `user_role` is declared in another form which is isn't a problem.

Comment: no the first thing that you are using mysql_ functions this was a security issue instead of that you may using PDO http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php ,the second thing what are you inserting in user_role when user registered that determine what ever is user is administrator or student

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$sel_admin = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username='$username'";
$rs_admin = mysql_query($sel_admin);
$rs_count = mysql_num_rows($rs_admin);

if($rs_count<1){
    echo 'Invalid username!';
}else{
$admin_info = mysql_fetch_array($rs_admin);
$adminid = $admin_info['user_id'];
$db_password = $admin_info['user_password'];
$user_role = $admin_info['user_role'];
if($password == $db_password){
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $adminid;

    if ($user_role == "Administrator") {
        header("Location: dashboard.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        header("Location: dashboard_student.php");
        exit;
    }
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect password!';
}
```

I've added a check on the user role.

If the user_role is Administrator it will redirect to the dashboard, else it will redirect to the Student dashboard.

You can always add more elseif ($user_role == "foobar") and then a header to that location. :)

Comment: Always add `exit;` after each header, otherwise the script will want to continue executing on failure; if any.

Comment: What would be the case scenario if i didn't include `exit;` and it executes on failure?